# check if sub-array is palindrome with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, palindrome

I need to find the sub-arrays centered in the middle of the original array and check if it is palindrome. After that I need to print the start index -1 and end index of the array.

I tried to do it but the outcome is not what I expected.
Can you point out any mistakes that I made?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_sub_pals(int *nums,int length)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < (length / 2); ++i)
    {
        for (int j = length -1 ; j < (length/2); j--)
        {
            int start = *(nums + i);
            int end = *(nums + j);
            if ((start) == (end))
            {
                cout << start - 1 << endl;
                cout << end << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "-1" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}



int main()
{
    int len = 7;
    int arr[7] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7 };
    print_sub_pals(arr, len);
}
```

Comment: `I tried to do it but the outcome is not what I expected`. Rather can you explicitly state your problem?

Comment: Second for loop condition `j < (length/2);` is not right

Comment: Sorry for not explain my problem clearly. I was trying to find the sub array and check if it is palindrome but the output didn't print anything. I guess i might do wrong with my array.

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables?  Is the code flow correct?

Comment: Possible duplicates:  ["stackoverflow c++ number palindrome"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+number+palindrome&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the second loop. Now at least it enters the loop, I think you still have to change it.

```
void print_sub_pals(int *nums, int length)
{
    //example: length is 7,
    //i = 0, goes up to 3
    for (int i = 0; i < (length / 2); ++i)
    {
        //j starts from 6, goes down, it stops when it's not less than 3
        //for (int j = length - 1; j < (length / 2); j--) {//never gets here} 

        //j starts from 6, goes down, it stops when it's less than 3
        for (int j = length - 1; j >= (length / 2); j--)
        {
            int start = *(nums + i);
            int end = *(nums + j);
            if ((start) == (end))
            {
                cout << start - 1 << endl;
                cout << end << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "-1" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem was already solved above with the fix on the second loop,  but a suggestion: it would be better to use only your first loop over i. You can change your start and end definitions to something like this:

```
        int start = *(nums + i); 
        int end = *(nums + length - i - 1);
```

With this addition, you can add a "break;" to your else statement to exit the loop immediately (if this is what you want to do) when an array violates the palindrome condition.

Edit: nums is pointer, so *(nums + i) for i = 0 is the first element.  To compare the true first and last elements, you should just print "start".

Comment: So this is just comparing an array with its reverse. What's with all the fancy talk on palindronic whatever...